# Boolean attributes in Weka

Tags: data-mining, weka, arff

Is it possible to implement boolean attributes in WEKA?

I want to implement a market basket analysis and for this I need a table such

```
Product_A Prod_B
Yes       No
No        Yes
Yes       Yes
```

and so on.

For `No`, or `false`, I can use `?`, that stands for a null value in WEKA:

```
Product_A Prod_B
Yes       ?
?         Yes
Yes       Yes
```

But now I get freq. itemsets and rules like:

```
Product_A=Yes, Prod_B=Yes
```

But I only want to have

```
Product_A, Prod_B.
```

Do you know what I mean?

I found a [guide](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file) about creating ARFF-Files but there aren't any boolean-datatypes..
But it would be useful to have such datatypes, or am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Just use a numeric attributes with 0 and 1 for false and true. ML algorithms generally don't care about booleans, and will treat them as numbers anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use `f` and `t` as nominal values. This is used in the `supermarket.arff` example file and is compatible to the Java API.

I created such a "boolean" attribute with this Java code:

```
FastVector tempBooleanValues = new FastVector();
tempBooleanValues.addElement("f");
tempBooleanValues.addElement("t");
tempAttributes.addElement(new Attribute("attribute_1", tempBooleanValues));
```

In the arff file, it looks like this:

```
@attribute attribute_1 {f,t}
...
transaction_1,f
transaction_2,t
```

Answer (score 1):

See the Weka `supermarket.arff` file for an example.

If you want to use the sparse format, it gets a bit more tricky IIRC; because missing values are by default replaced with their mode - which would be `Yes` then. But I believe the latest (not the book version) of Weka has improvements there.